# Redirecting after autocomplete selection in Django

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete

I have done an autocomplete search bar using Django and JQuery. I managed to get the selection written into the `textbox` but what I want to do is to redirect the user to an url which uses the data in the textbox.

Here are my HTML and JS files:

```
<script>

  $(function() {
    $("#places").autocomplete({
      source: "{% url "get_places" %}",
      select: function (event, ui) { //item selected
        AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
      },
      minLength: 2,
    });
  });

  function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
  {
    var selectedObj = ui.item;
  }

</script>
```

```html
<h1>Bienvenue sur le site de la Kfet !</h1>

<h2>Rechercher un Klient dans la barre de recherche ci-dessous :</h2>


<!-- jQuery !-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<!-- jQuery UI !-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="places">Rechercher un klient : </label>
  <input id="places">
</div>
```

I guess I have to put a kind of "link" in the JS file, but I don't know how to do it and to pass it the argument I want (the input text selected)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the URL coming from? What data is being sent for the autocomplete items?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I want to send the string written in the textbox (it's name and first name of people), then find the ID of this person in order to redirect to an interface of this person already done

Comment: So what do you have that will allow you to find the ID?

Comment: Nothing yet! Do I have to create an URL linking to a view (where I can do my python things to find the ID with the names) which redirect on the interface? I can do it but I still don't know how to implement it in Javascript... I just want to put a "validation" button in Javascript that call an URL with the input text in argument